# Html Css Beginner creating dropdown navbar menu

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner to css & html and creating have been having trouble with creating a dropdown menu inside navigation bar . In the drop down menu "Product" it doesnt show the dropdown menu list when clicked. If anyone can point out the issue I would be really grateful. Below is the HTML code for the navigation bar:

```css
.Navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4C4747;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.Navigation li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}
.Navigation li a {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}
.dropdown li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Navigation">
  <li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a>
  </li>

  <!-- Dropdown -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="Product.html" class="dropbtn">PRODUCT</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Computer.html">COMPUTER</a>
      <a href="Laptop.html">LAPTOP</a>
      <a href="Smartphone.html">SMARTPHONE</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!--  -->
  <li><a href="#news">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it this tutorial that you used as a source of inspiration? http://html.com/anchors-links/menus/#Adding_Drop-Down_Links_to_a_Horizontal_Navbar

Comment: No. Its project from campus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `.dropbtn` to `.dropdown-content` like this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```css
.Navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4C4747;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

.Navigation li a {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

.dropdown li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #4c4747;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Navigation">
<li><a href="Home.html">HOME</a></li>

          <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="Product.html" class="dropbtn">PRODUCT</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
           <a href="Computer.html">COMPUTER</a>
           <a href="Laptop.html">LAPTOP</a>
           <a href="Smartphone.html">SMARTPHONE</a>
         </div>
    </li>
            <!--  -->
    <li><a href="#news">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that @asdfg1234, then mark the answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.Navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4C4747;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}

.Navigation li a {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

.dropdown li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
     background-color: #4C4747;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover
{
  background-color:red;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/e4cxb2oe/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `.dropbtn` to `.dropdown-content` because then the button will be displayed (with `display: block;`) when you hover over `.dropdown` even though that is being displayed anyways. You want your *content* to be displayed when you hover over `.dropdown`. So change it to this-

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```